# Serving static files from static folder with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am attempting to serve static mp3 files with Flask so I can embed these mp3 files in an HTML audio block. I seem to be having an issue setting up the path correctly but I am not entirely sure if my problem is in my python or html.

An outline of my project:

```
music
    app.py
    static
        button.js
        MDF.mp3
    templates
        button.html
```

My app initialization in app.py looks like

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static")
```

The route in app.py looks like

```
@app.route("/<path:filename>")
def upload1():
    return send_static_file("MDF.mp3")
```

My default route:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    return render_template("button.html", title="Music Box", name="MyName", song1=songList[0], song2=songList[1], song3=songList[2])
```

And my button.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en-US xml: lang"en-US">
<body>
    <o1>
        <li> {{song1}}</li>
        <audio controls>
            src=upload1():
            Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
        </audio>
        <li> {{song2}}</li>
        <audio controls>
            src=upload2():
            Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
        <li> {{song3}}</li>
        <audio controls>
            src=upload3():
            Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
    </ol>

    <script src="/static/button.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error code I get is

```
10.245.81.226 - - [01/May/2019 04:25:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
10.245.81.226 - - [01/May/2019 04:25:08] "GET /static/button.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
10.245.81.226 - - [01/May/2019 04:25:08] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so please include the full stack trace.

Comment: @SuperShoot I have added my error codes to the original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have audio files in the `static` folder you can access them in templates using `url_for` as like other static files. Documentation of serving static files can be found [in this URL](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files).

Here I am showing an example of getting audio files URL in templates. I have passed the list of files from Flask app to the templates.

Directory structure:

```
├── app.py
├── static
│   ├── demo1.mp3
│   ├── demo2.mp3
│   └── demo3.mp3
└── templates
    ├── audio.html
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    audio_files = ["demo1.mp3", "demo2.mp3", "demo3.mp3"]
    return render_template('audio.html', audio_files=audio_files)
```

`audio.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Audio Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Serving audio files from Flask</h2>
   {% for file in audio_files %}
    <audio controls>
      <source src={{ url_for('static', filename=file) }} type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    {% endfor %}
    <p>Click on play icon to play</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output of audio files in flask app]

Comment: What to do if you dont know the file names in advance and they are dynamic. How do I get the list of all files available in static folder.

Comment: Hi Vineeth, you may create a new question for that. I think you can list the files of static folder using `os.listdir(app.static_folder)`.