# I get a 404 error when trying to play audio in HTML5, is there anyway to fix it?

Tags: html, flask, audio

Trying to create a simple website using HTML5 and have the following code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Generic Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then when I try to quickly host the server locally using Flask, I get a error that says...

```
"GET /audio.mp3 HHTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The audio file is in the same directory as the .html file so I don't know why I get this error. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Actually, you can put the .mp3 on the ```static``` folder first. Read for static documentation [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/). another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933447/serving-static-files-from-static-folder-with-flask) seems similar.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `./` at the front of your `src` value, which will tell the browser to look for the file in the current directory, rather than at the site root, `/`:

`<source src="./audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">`

Comment: For some reason, even though I added a ./ to my filename, it still gives me a 404 error even though the file-path directly links to the mp3 file. Is there anything else that might be an issue? Thanks

Comment: I missed that you had mentioned you were using Flask. You should refer to the two answers linked to above.